# Pushing an obejct to an state variable array based on checkbox checked/unchecked

Tags: reactjs

In my react application I have to pass an object to api end point like this:

```
{
  "name": "string",
  "description": "string",
  "permissions": [
    {
      "name": "string",
      "value": "string",
      "groupName": "string",
      "description": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

there are two text fields(for name and description) and and a checkbox(for permissions). If I checked the checkbox an object has to be push in permissions array and if I uncheck the checkbox array should be blank.
How do i do this? Please Help.
this is my codeblock:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, Component } from 'react';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import { Checkbox, FormControl, FormControlLabel, FormGroup, FormHelperText, FormLabel, Grid, makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';


export default class Index extends Component {
  state = {
    roleData: {
      name: '',
      description: '',
      permissions: []
    },
    viewUser: false
  }
  handleSubmit = () => {
    console.log(this.state.roleData);
  }
  handleViewUser = () => {
    if (this.state.viewUser) {
      this.state.roleData.permissions = [
        { data: 'abc' }
      ]
    }
    else {
      this.state.roleData.permissions = [
        { data: 'xyz' },
        { newData: 'pqr' }
      ]
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <TextField
          name={this.state.roleData.name}
          value={this.state.roleData.name}
          onChange={e => { this.setState({ roleData: { ...this.state.roleData, name: e.target.value } }); }}
        />
        <TextField
          style={{ marginTop: '20px' }}
          name={this.state.roleData.description}
          value={this.state.roleData.description}
          onChange={e => { this.setState({ roleData: { ...this.state.roleData, description: e.target.value } }); }}
        />
        <FormControlLabel
          control={<Checkbox
            checked={this.state.viewUser}
            onChange={e => { this.setState({ viewUser: e.target.checked }) }}
            onClick={this.handleViewUser}
          />}
          label="View User" />

        <Button variant="contained" color="primary" style={{ marginTop: '20px' }} onClick={this.handleSubmit} > Submit </Button>
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things you need to know

- setState
- push an item/value in the array.

here you can find how to set a state in react https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html

you can not add a value in an array by `=`. you need to push an item to the array. (ref: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp)

To answer your question, you can try the following the code.

```
handleViewUser = () => {
  const permissions = this.state.viewUser
    ? [{ data: "abc" }]
    : [{ data: "xyz" }, { newData: "pqr" }];

  this.setState((prevState) => ({
    ...prevState,
    permissions
  }));
```

Comment: the biggest problem is here. If I checked the checkbox handleViewUser method shows this.state.viewUser : false, and if I uncheck handleViewUser shows this.state.viewUser : true.

Comment: hello brother i need your help. do u have time now?

Comment: Feel free to contact me :)